# How to keep an image and a div text box the same size and responsive when scaling down in size?

Tags: html, css

I am currently using grid to make 2 columns that are equal to each other. One column has a div with the header and the other column has an image. How do I make sure the image on the right fills the entire column?

```css
#get-started-page .section1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.pink-box {
    background: #fee5d6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="get-started-page">
    <div class="section1">
        <div class="pink-box">
            <h1>Certification</h1>
            <h2 class="lowercase">#roadmaptocert</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg" alt="hair-stylist" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try giving 100% width and height to img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to fit the `img` to the parent's size. Also add `object-fit: cover` to adjust the aspect ratio of the `img`.

```css
#get-started-page .section1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.pink-box {
    background: #fee5d6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="get-started-page">
    <div class="section1">
        <div class="pink-box">
            <h1>Certification</h1>
            <h2 class="lowercase">#roadmaptocert</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg" alt="hair-stylist" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```